# Get the current page in a call back function

Tags: php

I would like to be able to get the URL of the page that I am crawling when the callback function is called. I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP REFERER']` but it gives me the URL of the page that the script is being called from, not the URL of the page being crawled.

How can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

You need the protocol, the host name and the (root relative) request URL. Then stick them together:

```
$scheme = 'http' . ( is_ssl() ? '' : 's' ) . '://';
$url    = $scheme . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: I get the same result, the URL of the page that called the script.

Comment: @user12920 That would be the referer, not request URI.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`. This will return you current page url without host

Comment: Please explain your code and how it is relevant to this question

Comment: This will return you current page url without host...!

Comment: You should add that as an [edit] to your answer.